# I can not find the word in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, unicode

I want program tell me if the word I wanted was in the text tag, but I do not know why he could not find word correctly
I tried find the word "آنچیتا" but it does not recognize it even though it is in the tag text.

The page I am scraping contains tr, td and the words I am looking for are persian word.

Is this problem related to unicode?

```
a=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for item in a:
   if 'آنچيتا' in item.text:    #the word is in text but can't match
       print('find it')
```

Comment: Can you share that web page link?

Comment: http://kia-kahroba.ir/laureates/fa/winners

Comment: I see no elements containing this sting on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tag_name tr
```

is basically representing a row. We don't wanna find rows, thus we can not use `tag_name`.

Use xpath instead :

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'آنچیتا')]")
for item in a:
   if 'آنچيتا' in item.text:    #the word is in text but can't match
       print('find it')
```

Comment: Thank
It works well
Can you Explain this section "// a [contains (text (), 'Anchita')"

Comment: that is basically xpath, and I have used contains method cause if you see in HTML there is trimming spaces where `آنچیتا` present and inside I have called text() cause we are looking for anchor tag that contains `آنچیتا`

Comment: Can you answer this question too?
It gives this error when I go to the next pages after passing a few pages..

Comment: Is there a new ticket created ? and what is the error btw ?

Comment: WebDriverWait(b, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.pager-next'))).click()

Comment: Error :selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <li class="pager-next"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: Have you written code to scroll down till the end of web page ?

Comment: No, I did not write a code to scroll down, I just take the information and go to the next page

Comment: You need to scroll till end of the webpage using this code `driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")`  and after that `WebDriverWait(b, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.pager-next'))).click() ` should work

Comment: Is it still the same issue you are experiencing ?

Comment: hmmm.. Can you create a new ticket with exact same issue ? Probably somebody can also have a look.. Meanwhile I am heading outside right now, will try to have a look once I am back

Comment: thank u man ,You answered many questions for me

Comment: Not an issue bro.. keep rocking !